# Copying/Rename JSON Object Array

Tags: javascript, json

Am getting Data from server in below JSON format

```
{
"Data": [
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Number": 0,
        "Modify": {
            "Id": 0,
            "Name": "a"
        }
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Number": 1,
        "Modify": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "b"
        }
    }
]}
```

And am trying to create a new copy(Rename) of **Modify** inside the same object because my other data is expecting JSON with same format but different name for modify.

So i though i would foreach and create copy of the same which will form like below

```
{
"Data": [
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Number": 0,
        "Modify": {
            "Id": 0,
            "Name": "a"
        },"New": {
            "Id": 0,
            "Name": "a"
        }
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Number": 1,
        "Modify": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "b"
        },
     "New": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "b"
        }
    }
]}
```

Is there a better approach i can rename the object  or should i create a copy. What is the better way to copy ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For loop is a fine way to do that.. `data[i].Name = data[i].Modify;`. Im fairly sure there isn't a "better" way than this in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There's no other way than the one suggested by @MjrKusanagi, nevertheless I suggest another approach.

Make a function that takes your original object and replaces the selected key with the new name, returning a new object without changing the original one (immutability)

The function could take 3 arguments:

```
function modifyObject(object, oldKey, newKey) {...}
```

Inside the function you could use the [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method to create a copy of the original object (a copy, not a reference):

```
var newObj = Object.assign({}, object);
```

After that, you can change the key name by creating a new one and don't forget to remove old key from the new object:

```
newObj.newKey = newObj.oldKey;
delete newObj.oldKey,
```

Finally you can return this new object and even use this function every time you need to do anything similar.

Using the `delete` is considered bad practice, but at least here you are not mutating your original source, so you can depend in its content over all your application's life cycle.